# How to find DOM child nodes only within a specific div with a give class name?

Tags: javascript

I have a hierarchical `div` section as follows:

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <button class="class3" onclick="bclick(this)">b1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="class4">
        <p>first text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <button class="class3" onclick="bclick(this)">b2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="class4">
        <p>second text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <button class="class3" onclick="bclick(this)">b3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="class4">
        <p>third text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <button class="class3" onclick="bclick(this)">b4</button>
    </div>
    <div class="class4">
        <p>fourth text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on any button, say button `b3`, I want to get the text `third text` in javascript, not jquery.

So in my `bclick()` function, I am getting to the root element as follows:

```
function bclick(obj) {
    let class1obj = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
    // don't know what to do next to get to class 4 and then get the <p> text.
}
```

I want to get into `class4` to get the content of `<p>` tag, in this case for `b3` text I want is `third text`.

Not sure how to do. Since there a multiple occurrence of a class, I want to get only a specific class which contains the button clicked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) on parent and select the `<p>` element inside `.class4` for each parent element.

```
obj.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.class4 p')
```

See the working snippet

```js
function bclick(elm){
  const parent = elm.parentNode.parentNode;
  console.log(parent.querySelector('.class4 p').innerHTML)
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <button class="class3" onclick="bclick(this)">b1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="class4">
        <p>first text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <button class="class3" onclick="bclick(this)">b2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="class4">
        <p>second text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <button class="class3" onclick="bclick(this)">b3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="class4">
        <p>third text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <button class="class3" onclick="bclick(this)">b4</button>
    </div>
    <div class="class4">
        <p>fourth text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Document​.query​Selector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) on the parent node:

> The Document method `querySelector()` returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

```js
function bclick(obj) {
  let class1obj = obj.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.class4 > p');
  console.log(class1obj.textContent);
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <button class="class3" onclick="bclick(this)">b1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="class4">
        <p>first text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <button class="class3" onclick="bclick(this)">b2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="class4">
        <p>second text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <button class="class3" onclick="bclick(this)">b3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="class4">
        <p>third text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <button class="class3" onclick="bclick(this)">b4</button>
    </div>
    <div class="class4">
        <p>fourth text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to improve the accepted answer in two regards:

1. It is widely considered bad practice to use inline event listeners, so I'll rather use `HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener`.
2. Instead of doing  `parentNode.parentNode` it is more reliable and robust towards possible future changes in DOM structure to use `Element.prototype.closest` which finds the nearest ancestor matching the selector passed as an argument.

```js
for (const button of document.querySelectorAll('.class3')) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const pText = this.closest('.class1').querySelector('.class4 p').textContent;
    console.log(pText);
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <button class="class3">b1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="class4">
    <p>first text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <button class="class3">b2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="class4">
    <p>second text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <button class="class3">b3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="class4">
    <p>third text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <button class="class3">b4</button>
  </div>
  <div class="class4">
    <p>fourth text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```